# Special character in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, special-characters

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VqqwU63pLz7OgeE4jZRn?p=preview)

I have a string that contains a decoded HTML entity:

'ó'

`&#243;`

I need to display this `string` IN an INPUT ELEMENT through the `ng-model` value, but display it with the character, not the the decoded entity. I have tried using a `$parser` with `$sce` but this didn't seem to work.

I have tried a few different methods but nothing seems to work

```
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce){
    $scope.char = $sce.trustAsHtml('&#243;') 
  })
  .directive('trustedHtml', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
          console.log(value)
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
        });
      }
    }
  }])
```

any ideas?

---

[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rA4DeNfe4ZWjQ302uILt?p=preview) below based on @Meiko 's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to htmlDecode the string:

```
    function htmlDecode(input){
      var elem = document.createElement('div');
      elem.innerHTML = input;
      return elem.childNodes.length === 0 ? '' : elem.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
```

and to make your example working use formatters instead of parsers:

```
ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
    return htmlDecode(value);
});
```

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $sce){
    $scope.char = $sce.trustAsHtml('ALK-Abell&#243; A/S') 
  })
  .directive('trustedHtml', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          function htmlDecode(input){
            var elem = document.createElement('div');
            elem.innerHTML = input;
            return elem.childNodes.length === 0 ? '' : elem.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          }
          return htmlDecode(value);
        });
      }
    }
  }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    ALK-Abell&#243; A/S <br>
    <input trusted-html ng-model="char"/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you! I gotta remember to just stick with some good old vanilla js every now and then

Comment: Your solution not working if i put direct html code like this
`$sce.trustAsHtml("<p>sajfasfjhs</p> <br> <h3>skhfksjdf</h3>")` . what is the solution for it